# Rebase or cherry pick these commits?

Tags: git, github

I tried my hand at rebasing not long ago, and royally screwed myself up.

After some aborted attempts I have my files in the shape they need to be, but my commit history looks a ugly when I prepare a pull request on github:

[image: list of commits]

I'd like to squash all that to a single commit before opening the PR but don't know how.  If I try `git rebase -i HEAD~5` I get commits from others showing in the list (probably because I merged from master at some point?)

I can't easily cherry pick since there are merge commits in there, and I have no idea how to pull that off, cherry picking involving merges.

As I mentioned, if I open a PR now the files are as they should be, but I know the repo manager is going to ask me to squash that history.  I'm looking for suggestions on what to do?

Edit: in response to a request for more information, this is the graph from sourcetree, my git client.  Hope it helps (I realize I'm not posting 100% information, and don't necessarily expect a silver bullet of an answer, but am hoping for an approach.)

[image]

Wow, that doesn't look good at all in the post. 
[Here's the link to the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYCmu.png)

Comment: Could you please give more info about the look of your git history? In particular it doesn't seem clear to me what it looks like wrt to merge commits

Comment: Not 100% sure, but can't you just create a new branch and then cherry pick all the non-merge commits into that branch, one by one?

Comment: @gturri Sorry about that. Just added a graphical representation of the log

Comment: @KeillRandor, I thought so too, but somehow one of my changes is _only_ in one of the merge commits-- I have no idea how that happened.  I really pulled a number on my rebase attempt I suppose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'd like to squash all that to a single commit

Then you don't need `rebase`, you can simply use `reset` and `commit`.

```
git reset --soft origin/master
git commit
```

`git reset --soft` will update your current branch to the same commit as `origin/master`, but without updating your index or working tree, so after that, all of your changes are still in the index and ready to be committed again.

Comment: I'll try that, thanks very much (to you and Alexander.)  Sorry I wasn't as clear in my diagram as I might have been, but didn't want to chance revealing anything I shouldn't have...

Answer (score 1):

Ah, this is really tough to figure out without having the complete history etc. at hand, but I would assume that `HEAD~5` is the culprit. You are going too far back into history - there are only 3 commits on your actual branch, as far as I can tell. Could you try rebasing by specifying the commit hash explicitly? E.g.

```
git rebase -i <parent-of-d9e6a34>
```

where you'd replace `<parent-of-d9e6a34>` with the actual commit hash of course.

EDIT: `git rebase -i d9e6a34~1` should do the same.